# mapstruct and gradle configuratoin issue in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, mapstruct

I have a project using gradle, and have mapstruct as one of dependency. everytime I tried to build project, it failed. I guess it is because Mapstruct will generate impl class that gradle was not able to find. Can anyone help me how to configure this in intellij IDEA?

Thanks

Comment: did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me

In intellij IDEA go to

File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner

Enable Delegate IDE build/run actions. 
Ref :- https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3-gradle

In build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...    
}
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.9'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.1.0.Final'
    apt 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.1.0.Final'
}
```

After Adding this configuration Run your project you can see your generated files in build/generated folder

Answer (score 2):

Hey there everyone I had the same issue and found a clean way of solving this issue.
I am using two libraries that require annotation processing (Lombok and MapStruct).

Also my IntelliJ is 2019.1 (update yours in case it's older) and Gradle 5.2.1.

First let's configure IntelliJ:

1. Disable Annotaion Processing in Settings, since we're going to delegate everything to Gradle:

[image]

2. Delegeate IDE actions to Gradle:

[image]

Last step is to configure your dependencies correctly in Gradle.

3. Dependencies section in Gradle:

[image]

Now you can execute the Build and Run from both command line and IDE.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From Mac OS

1. Please remove `build` generated folder.
2. Click Intellij IDEA => click `Preferences...` from menu => Select `Build, Execution, Deployment` => Select `Gradle` => Select `Runner`
3. Tick into `Deledate IDE build/run actions to gradle` checkbox
4. From run tests using: select `Gradle Test Runner` from dropdown list.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Another setting I found helpful was to uncheck "Create separate module per source set"
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Uncheck "Create separate module per source set"